# Eloquent query search in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

If i have a db column called 'search_terms' with contains an array like `["test","one","one two"]`.

I am trying to match search terms, so far i have:

```
Image::where( 'search_terms', 'like', "%{$term}%" )->get();
```

But looking for a way to to match exactly one of the terms in the array, so the term "one" would only match 1 result and not 2. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the column is contain string value like this `["test","one"]`, you need to add `"` with search - make this like `%"{$term}"%` - with respect for escape character

Comment: works thanks @AbdelrhmanMohamed

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the current setup in a purely SQL fashion.  For one, it's impossible to find where there's just one occurence.  Also, "%four%" will match on "%fourteen%"  which also probably isn't what you want.  You would need to normalize and split up the array into another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you storing string formatted like array `[""]` - since you search in string like array `"%\"{$term}\"%"`

```
Image::where( 'search_terms', 'like', "%\"{$term}\"%" )->get();
```